# Redirect Extensions Directory for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have started playing around with VSCode and Im finding it has alot to offer.

Im running into one issue with a few extensions that need admin rights to install. On my network our user and admin accounts are split up and our admin doesn't have access to the internet, I was looking around and found I can redirect the user directory but when I provide an extensions directory it doesn't work. The folder gets created but nothing gets added to it. Below is the command im running, can someone show me what Im doing wrong.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Toolbox\vscode" --extensionHomePath="C:\Toolbox\vscode\extensions"
```

My end goal is to pull down extensions when Im running it as my user and then when it needs admin rights to enable or install I would just relaunch the application as my admin so it can update. If im going at this all wrong and there is an easier way please let me know.

Comment: What is requiring admin rights?  Your extension should be installing into `C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions`, which you don't typically require admin privileges to modify.

Comment: The one i would like is vscode-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the `vscode-icons` extension, I recommend that you **just don't use it**.  It modifies VSCode itself, which is *not* what a well-behaved extension should be doing.  Don't encourage this behavior.  Instead, encourage the VSCode development team to extend the extension API.

If you are going to use it anyhow, here's my guess on what you will need to do:

1. Install the extension under your administrative account and enable it, [as described in the instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons).
2. Copy the the extension (likely a folder) from the admin account's extensions directory to your non-admin extensions directory.
3. Follow the instructions on the marketplace to make sure [your settings are updated as instructed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons).

**CAUTION: This extension is likely to break each time you update VSCode.  Further, if the extension incorrectly modifies a future version of VSCode, it may end up breaking the IDE itself.**

Comment: Sorry for the late reaponse. With it not being best practice i wont use it. I will put a feature request in for it on the github page. Thanks.